# France speeding tickets

Tags: france, car

There was a time when I was young and (very) stupid.

I had a car, registered under my name, in France (near Geneva). Just before leaving the region and selling the car, I did a trip to Lyon. Since I was in a hurry, and reckless, I did speed up quite a bit (about 180 km/h). Since I left the area very soon after and sold the car, I didn't see any fines.

Is there any way to check if there are any fines under my name? Will they chase them?

Comment: Presumably you'll be notified by mail at the address you used for your vehicle registration.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to the letters I receive at the old address (there is no policy for keeping the letters of old tenants).

Comment: You may need to speak to the French motor licensing authority and let them know a forwarding address, and ask them if there is some way you could find out about notices of violation.